# How to grab first para from string and crop it if it exceeds a limit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to show a small snippet of my articles on the homepage , something like below:

[image]

For the content below the headings i have the following line of code to trim down the content:

```
{!! str_limit($recent->blog_content , 50 , '...') !!}
```

The problem is sometimes the description can be something like  the below in the database.

```
<p>I Love javascript as you will see below:</p>
<pre class="language-javascript"><code>tinymce.init({
    selector: '#description-textbox',
    plugins: "codesample",
    codesample_languages: [
            {text: 'HTML/XML', value: 'markup'},
            {text: 'JavaScript', value: 'javascript'},
            {text: 'CSS', value: 'css'},
            {text: 'PHP', value: 'php'}
    ],
    toolbar: 'codesample | undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image'
});</code></pre>
<p>Now thats what i&aacute;m talking about !! A HU-MUN-GUS javascript snippet ...</p>
```

Its a string in the database, now i get content in my frontend that looks like below:

[image]

So now i would like the below line of code:

```
 {!! str_limit($recent->blog_content , 50 , '...') !!}
```

To be changed in such a way that it grabs the text from the 1st paragraph and if the text in that para exceeds 50 characters then trim it , how do i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that you have `$text`, and you need to take the first paragraph of it.
you can do it like this:

```
$paragraph = explode("\n", $text);
```

and then you can do the `str_limit` on `$paragraph`